# Does a DNS A record redirect slow down load speeds? (with example)

Tags: dns, webserver, zone

I have a website hosted on my server that is taking longer to load than our other websites despite the fact that it's built the same. To test further, I made an exact copy of the website and put it on a sub-domain.

I noticed that the sub-domain copy load anywhere from 10%-70% faster every time. The only difference I can think of is that the live site's DNS is pointed elsewhere, and just uses an A record to redirect to our servers.

Is this the reason why? If so, is there any ways to avoid this?

You can see the website and it's clone and test their speeds at whichloadsfaster.com

http://tinyurl.com/9vmebl9 vs. http://tinyurl.com/8dg6evt

Answer (score 2):

Difference in DNSrequest is minor. Changes from 0.1 to 0.2 seconds each time.

I checked your links and now I can actually see differences. It seem likt the subdomain loads faster. This could be a server configuration issue. However there are several linked files (internal and external) that are missing (reset.css,uclass.css,body-bg.gif,museoslab-500-webfont.ttf etcetera) also FB links load on very different times.

I also notice the HTTP GET for /british-columbia/ is 23.7 KB on the subdomain but 23.9 KB on the main domain (I haven't checked why but it seem the documents are different?)

My few tips in optimizing for speed is:

- use gzip compression
- use clever caching for different content
- put as much javascript as possible just before `</body>`

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Actually I wasn't aware of the missing linked files. What did you use to check for that?

Although I'm all for optimizing the current site speed, I'm more concerned about why it's up to 3x slower to load on the live site than it is on the sub domain. I'm not sure what the slight difference is in file size, but even if they're slightly different, they're about 99% the same.

Perhaps it's the Facebook links. I'll try removing that and do some tests.

Comment: Tried removing the Share This script, but didn't seem to make much of a difference. Will keep looking.

Comment: @norsewulf My standard debug tool is firebug for firefox, on the Net tab you can see a graphic representation of load times for all parts of the web page. What is striking is that the initial load time of the actual html file IS longer for the main domain.

Answer (score 0):

Load times are only affected by DNS resolution at extreme levels. This doesn't appear to be the case for you.

It's far more likely to be a configuration issue on your host, and how traffic is directed within the web server's network.

Comment: Do you have any specific ideas in regards to server configuration? I'm in touch with my server support team, but hopefully I can give them some sort of suggestion as to where to look.